# How could JVM memory erratically grow to 3x normal, but symptoms stop after OS patching with no code push

Tags: memory, jvm

We have a Java app that runs in Java 8 using gencon garbage collection (that seems to be working). There are multiple load balanced (round robin) servers all sharing the work, and transactions are theoretically pretty homogenous. Normally we are around 30% memory utilization on these servers.

We had a several week period (perhaps coincidentally) starting after our last OS patching where we were getting memory utilization alerts on some of our app servers (2 of 4 frequently, 1 of 4 less frequently, and the fourth not at all) and had to manually stop the app and restart to avoid the app using all 32GB of RAM on the server and crashing due to OOM (out of memory). The OS memory that was claimed exceeded Xmx significantly (which is permitted by our overcommit settings, but not normally seen), and we run a JRE (do not have a JDK on this server) so we can't use jmap, jcmd, or other utilities to get diagnostics. We did use Xdump to get heap dumps and the live objects on the heap were less than 1 GB when the JVM was using >25GB of OS memory. Here is some data we could get before a restart on one of the servers:

```
Memory
  ^[[1mCurrent heap size^[[22m           7,628,085 kbytes
  ^[[1mMaximum heap size^[[22m           16,777,216 kbytes
  ^[[1mCommitted heap size^[[22m         11,558,656 kbytes
  ^[[1mPending objects^[[22m             0
  ^[[1mGarbage collector^[[22m           Name = 'scavenge', Collections = 762, Time = 12.923 seconds
  ^[[1mGarbage collector^[[22m           Name = 'global', Collections = 24, Time = 14.408 seconds
Classes
  ^[[1mCurrent classes loaded^[[22m      56,936
  ^[[1mTotal classes loaded^[[22m        253,720
  ^[[1mTotal classes unloaded^[[22m      196,784
Operating system
  ^[[1mName^[[22m                        Linux version 3.10.0-1160.105.1.el7.x86_64
  ^[[1mArchitecture^[[22m                amd64
  ^[[1mProcessors^[[22m                  4
  ^[[1mTotal physical memory^[[22m       32,304,924 kbytes
  ^[[1mFree physical memory^[[22m        2,034,216 kbytes
  ^[[1mCommitted virtual memory^[[22m    27,052,276 kbytes
  ^[[1mTotal swap space^[[22m            0 kbytes
  ^[[1mFree swap space^[[22m             0 kbytes
```

Following a hunch we built a new ec2 from an AMI image of the one server that did not exhibit memory growth to replace the one of the servers that was doing it frequently. The newly built server kept using up all the OS memory just like it did before we built it.

We did numerous comparisons across the servers to look for code and config differences, and found none.

We patched last weekend, and have not seen the memory utilization grow past 35% so far this week. This is a significant improvement over last week when we had to reboot servers daily.

Can you please make recommendations for getting to a root cause on this, or direct how we may investigate it for root cause if it happens again?